# Remove values in vector from double variable in R

Tags: r, list, variables, vector, double

I have a variable of type double `X: 1.5 1.3 0.6 1.8 2.9 2.1 1.5 1.4 5.8 0.0` 
and a vector `V: c(0.6,2.9)`. I want to remove the values in `V` from `X`

```
 test<-X[!X %in% V]
```

The values are not removed from test:

```
test
 [1] 1.5 1.3 0.6 1.8 2.9 2.1 1.5 1.4 5.8 0.0`
```

I tried the following:

```
are.equal <- function(x, y, eps = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) abs(x - y) < eps
    test=X[!(are.equal(X,0.6))]
```

0.6   were removed..
I could have something odd in my data or my system.
Any idea?

Comment: What do you think the call to `any` is doing for you?

Comment: I just tested `X [! X %in% V]` with your input vectors and it works just fine for me.  What is the problem?

Comment: My guess is that Pascal assumed that the data AWRAM had printed is what was actually stored when they edited the question but the data in R wasn't quite so clean.

Comment: @Dason Yes I have this feeling also.  It seems that the OP is inconsistent with the state of his R console.

Comment: Yes, I tend to assume too much. Rolled back.

Comment: @Dason I wanted to apply the are.equal function to the elements in the vector V

Comment: If I do X[!are.equal(X, 0.6)] then 0.6 is rmoved

Comment: You don't need your custom function, your proposed code already works. Just try it again because something odd is going on on your side.

Comment: Anyway some down votes are not fair for who (like me) try to answer. immediately I realized that my answer was "incorrect" (because the code of OP was already working) I immediately removed it. The problem is that some users first down vote and then comment. it should be the contrary from my point of view.

Comment: @SabDeM  I am pretty sure that a majority of downvoters don't even take time to comment.

Comment: @AWRAM Isn't that exactly what you would expect?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I have no idea what was going on but I did X<-round(X) and then the original test<-X[!X %in% V] worked ...